# how to check KEY for existence in json.RawMessage on GO?

Tags: go

I have a:

```
type User struct {
    UID                     int          `json:"id"`
    FirstName               string       `json:"first_name"`
    LastName                string       `json:"last_name"`
    Sex                     int          `json:"sex"`
    Nickname                string       `json:"nickname"`
    ScreenName              string       `json:"screen_name"`
    BDate                   string       `json:"bdate"`

}
```

code:

```
var userList []*User
json.Unmarshal(resp.Response, &userList)
```

server response may be:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"name","last_name":"last","sex":2,"nickname":"","screen_name":"screen","bdate":"1.1.1"}]
```

or

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"name","sex":2,"nickname":"","screen_name":"screen"}]
```

my problem when calling a nonexistent KEY error runtime "`userList[0].LastName`":

```
error: index out of range
```

in the first case, the server returned:

```
"last_name":"last" and "bdate":"1.1.1"
```

in the second no

When there is no user, the server returns.

```
[{"error_code": 0, "error_msg": "Invalid user id"}]
```

answer:

```
    if len(userList) > 0 {
            c.String(http.StatusOK, "People name: %s", userList[0].FirstName)
        } else {
            c.String(http.StatusOK, "No People: %s", login)
        }
```

Thank Magestro

Comment: are you sure you want to have the pointer there? IMO you should write `var userList []User`

Comment: The information presented in the question is inconsistent.  All of the example JSON documents unmarshal to a slice with length > 0 (see https://play.golang.org/p/N34S0opAQPp), but a user is only specified in first two.

Comment: Error checking in script before len (userList)

if handler.Error != nil {
  return nil, handler.Error
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error: index out of range` means that `userList` have no value with index `[0]`, not about empty `LastName`

In your example all works fine: https://play.golang.org/p/WHIqgB52w_I

A u sure that server returns valid string and that this string exists in the `resp.Response`?

Try print `resp.Response` and look for error in other place

Comment: In this case server returns `object`, not an `array`. 
So this response can't unmarshall into slice type. 
U have at least 2 solutions: 

1) Create custom 
```
type UsersResponse struct {
 Error struct {
  Cose int
  Msg string
  RequestParams map[string]string
 }
 Users []*User
}
```
And create custom unmarshall funcs for this type

2) Check's error like this: https://play.golang.org/p/a7sUT5T_EOn